# How can I write a self join that combines rows based on the value of a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched but was unable to find an answer to this scenario.  I have a table that contains 2.5 mil rows of accounts. Those accounts appear at least 3 times each and are identified by an alphanumeric identifier, account_id.  The 3 rows per account are all identifcal except for 2 columns, profile_name, which contains 1 of 3 string values (we'll call then 'one, 'two' and 'three') and a distributor_id which is a numeric identifier.  The structure looks like this (not limited to these fields but they're what I care about):

```
account_id        profile_name        distributor_id
PX198             'one'               123
PX198             'two'               987
PX198             'three'             573
AZ476             'one'               123
AZ476             'two'               652
```

My question is how can I write a self join query to return something like this:

```
account_id        distributor_one_id   distributor_two_id   distributor_three_id
    PX198         123                  987                  573
    AZ476         123                  652                  NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in more efficient way:

```
SELECT
    account_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN profile_name = 'one' THEN distributor_id END) as distributor_one_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN profile_name = 'two' THEN distributor_id END) as distributor_two_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN profile_name = 'three' THEN distributor_id END) as distributor_three_id
FROM tbl
GROUP BY account_id
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3465c/1)**

Answer (score 2):

If you can have at maximum three profile_names, you could join your table like this:

```
SELECT
  t1.account_id,
  t1.distributor_id AS distributor_one_id,
  t2.distributor_id AS distributor_two_id,
  t3.distributor_id AS distributor_three_id
FROM
  yourtable t1 LEFT JOIN yourtable t2
  ON t1.account_id = t2.account_id
     AND t2.profile_name = 'two'
  LEFT JOIN yourtable t3
  ON t1.account_id = t3.account_id
     AND t3.profile_name = 'three'
WHERE
  t1.profile_name = 'one'
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2a21/1).